# PostGIS - can't create spatially-enabled database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, gis, postgis, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10, PostgreSQL 9.0 and PostGIS 1.5.

I've installed PostGIS 1.5 from:
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable

I used PPA first then the command:

```
sudo apt-get install postgis
```

to install postgis.
I've been following these instructions to create a spatially-enabled database:

http://ostgis.refractions.net/docs/ch02.html

I got to the point where it's saying:

> Now load the PostGIS object and
>   function definitions into your
>   database by loading the postgis.sql
>   definitions file (located in
>   [prefix]/share/contrib as specified
>   during the configuration step).
>
> psql -d [yourdatabase] -f postgis.sql

Well, there is no postgis.sql on my server after the installation. I did an sudo updatedb to make sure I can find postgis.sql but it's not there.
Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "ubuntugis-unstable" PPA repository that you're using does **not** ship PostGIS for PostgreSQL 9.0. It includes a package named "`postgresql-8.4-postgis`", which contains the file `/usr/share/postgresql/8.4/contrib/postgis-1.5/postgis.sql`. This is what they're referring to.

Unfortunately, the PPA does not include a version of the PostGIS extension for PostgreSQL 9.0 because 9.0 isn't yet shipped with any Ubuntu release. It will be included in the upcoming Ubuntu 11.04 Natty, which will probably also ship an up-to-date PostGIS in the official repositories.

So, you can [follow these instructions to build your own PostGIS](http://www.tokumine.com/2010/10/12/postgres-9-postgis-1-5-2-geos-3-2-2-and-gdal-1-7-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/), or stick with PostgreSQL 8.4 from the official repos.

edit: ubuntu 11.04 don't ship postgres 9.0

Comment: I'd stick with 8.4 (unless you need the new binary replication features).

Comment: You are right, it is for PostgreSQL 8.4. Though it works with the Ubuntu 10.10 I'm not sure why I assumed it was for the PostgreSQL 9.0.

Comment: I built my own PostGIS and it worked with PostgreSQL 9. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The newers Postgres and Postgis versions that work with it are available from

https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql/+packages

Following [this guide](http://www.tokumine.com/2010/10/12/postgres-9-postgis-1-5-2-geos-3-2-2-and-gdal-1-7-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid/) that incorporates all needed software for PostGIS, you can set it up easily. It's for 10.04 but the PPA works with 10.10 as well.

I'd recommend 9.x and the latest PostGIS since we had severe (known) speed problems for a project. SO choose either 8.3 or 9.0.

Comment: I needed Postgresql 9 that's why I did wall possible to stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tutorial for PostGIS 8.4 on Ubuntu 10.10 [here](http://cols-code-snippets.blogspot.com/2010/11/install-postgrespostgis-on-ubuntu.html).